# Calling Operator() "function call" to return reference to array element

Tags: c++, functor

I think I don't really understand what's behind references, and I'd be glad to learn more about those.

I'm writing a math "vector" Class to do basic linear algeabra for numerical simulation. I was using Eigen before i was convinced not to use external libraries anymore. My problem is pretty straightforward :

- I declare vector and sets its 3 components of type `Scalar` (these are doubles). I can do math with my vectors as I overload operators, but this is beyond the scope of my question.
- I want to access the i-th component of my object through the function call operator () as I was used with Eigen : `myVector(0) = 0.0 ;` or `Scalar d = myVector(0)+1.0 ;`

According to my understanding of references, this solution should be working :

```
class mtnVector {
public:
    typedef double Scalar;
    Scalar  data [3];
    (setters, math, etc...)
    inline Scalar & operator() (const int i) const {
        return data[i] ; 
    }
};
```

But g++ says that it doesn't like the way I implement it and comfirms I s*** at references : 
`Vector.h:185: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ?double&? from expression of type ?const double?`

What's very strange from my point of view is that if the array containing the data is dynamically set (`Scalar * data`) (with new operator) at class construction, the code compiles fine. But I don't see the point of having dynamically set data holder.

I don't get neither the need of const to overload the function call operator but I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator()` is declared `const`. This means that calling the function should never end up modifying the object. That function returns a member of this object by non-`const` reference, which would allow whoever called `operator()` to modify the internals of the object. Obviously this would be silly, so the compiler just doesn't allow it. If you're going to return a reference to a member from a `const` member function, you need to make that reference `const`:

```
inline const Scalar& operator() (const int i) const {
    return data[i] ; 
}
```

You might want to provide both a `const` and non-`const` version of the function, one of which returns a `const Scalar&` and the other a `Scalar&` (this is [how the standard library containers do it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)).

It seems strange that you'd want to use `operator()` for this. Your expression `myVector(0)` would look more natural as `myVector[0]`, which you can achieve through overloading `operator[]` instead.

Also, you should ignore whoever convinced you that you shouldn't use external libraries. Eigen, in particular, is a very mature and thoroughly tested library. Unless you really have a good reason, you should be using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have some troubles to get the scope of the const thing. The external libraries issue is because I'm not a computer guy, I use C++ to do numerical simulations and people around me are more or less stuck with Fortran 90 and the dusty "Numerical Recipies". What's "external" is devil and I deal with it :) ...

Comment: Putting `const` at the end of the function declaration says that this function can only be called on a `const` object. That means the object should be constant. If your `const` member function modifies the object in any way, the compiler will complain. Your function doesn't do it directly, but it *does* return a reference to something that is part of the object by non-`const` reference. This allows whoever called the function to modify that internal part of the object even though the object is `const`. This is bad! So your function, if it is `const`, *must* only return const references.

Comment: Well, I implemented both and it works like a charm :) I can switch between Eigen or my own vectors/matrices with your great help, and I will keep on using Eigen and keep my own classes as backup solution when people will say I do bad code when I use external libraries... I understand now why g++ was throwing all those errors. Thank you @sftrabbit !!!!